# Talking to a network device

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, protocols, device

I have a device on my network that I need to get data out of using C#. I know I have to use sockets within C# but does anyone know of any program that lets me trial sending and receiving data from this device. For example going by some very vague documentation i have, i can pass the device a binary number and it will send me back a result. Is there any software which will let me test this?? Thankyou

Comment: What do you mean by "device"? Providing some specifics would help get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The question felt a bit vague, but here goes with what I hope will be an acceptable answer:

You'll need to get some more information on the protocol. For myself, after I've gathered what information I know, I usually write a small script in Linqpad in order to craft packets and record responses.

It might help to use a third party software to listen to the responses, like wireshark / microsoft network monitor.  Also, just listening to the devices chatter can help with the process, and you can do this with the aforementioned wireshark or MNM.  In order to be most effective, you'll need to be listening to the traffic using a hub or network tee.

Have fun.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Unix use Net Cat (abbreviated to nc): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat

It allows you to do simple tests of network client/server software (such as send data from file to the socket or listen socket an respond with some data from a file). Great tool for network protocol developers.

And of course, Wireshark/tcpdump to sniff and replay network activity.

Be more specific in your question about the OS and your task.